# How to install Google Play Services on a 6.0 Visual Studio Emulator?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-emulator

I have followed the solution provided [by Rob Prouse here](http://www.alteridem.net/2015/10/28/installing-google-play-services-gapps-on-visual-studio-android-emulators/) to install Google Play Services on a Visual Studio Emulator running the Android 5.1.1 with API Level 22. This all worked well, and the maps in my application successfully worked, however, I am looking to make this work on a 6.0 device.

Rob Prouse Solution:

> 1 - Download the correct GAPPS for the Android version from http://www.teamandroid.com/gapps/
>       2 - Use the Additional Tools (small >> icon) for the emulator and go to the SD Card tab.
>       3 - Select a folder on your computer to sync with the virtual SD card.
>       4 - **Pull from SD card**, which will create a folder structure on the selected folder.
>       5 - Now copy the Gapps fill to the ‘Download’ folder.
>       6 - **Push to SD card.** This will take a little while, and copy the zip file to your emulator.
>       7 - Run a commmand prompt, and go to **sdk\platform-tools** in your Android SDK location and run **adb devices.**
>       8 - If you see the your emulator in the list, then skip to step 10.
>       9 - If you do not see emulator, run the following: **adb connect <emulator ip>:5555** You can find the emulator ip, from within the emulator, go to Settings -> About Phone -> Status and IP section.
>       10 - Next run, **adb shell.** This will give you a prompt to the android emulator.
>       11 - Confirm the gapps file is there: **ls /sdcard/Download**
>       12 - Now run, **install_zip.sh /sdcard/Download/.zip** This should begin the flashing process.
>       13 - Once the flashing is complete, restart the emulator.
>       14 - Once you restart, you may see errors with apps like Google+ trying to start up, ignore them for now.
>       15 - Sign into your Google account and upgrade all apps from Google Play.
>       16 - When you run your application that requires Google Play services, you may be prompted to upgrade

I tried all three packages from http://www.teamandroid.com/gapps/, but none worked.
Note that the `HDPI / MDPI / TINY: gapps-600-base-20151016-1-signed.zip` installed the play store, but it keeps crashing and never opens.
I tried both `adb` commands and drag-and-drop solutions.
**Has anyone been able to install the google play services into a 6.0 Visual Studio Emulator?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up following another documentation about the emulator, and it worked well.
For anyone who is having the same problem, take a look at this one:
http://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2016/04/installing-gapps-in-visual-studio.html

Solution from source:

> **Prerequisites**
>       1. Install a Marshmallow image in the Visual [Studio Emulator for Android tools](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/) (can be opened through *Tools > Visual Studio Emulator for Android* in Visual Studio)
>       2. Download [gapps-L-4-21-15.zip](https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=96042739161891406)
>       3. Download [benzo-gapps-M-20151011-signed-chroma-r3.zip](https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=24052804347835438)
>
> **Installing**
>       1. Start the Marshmallow image
>       2. Drag the *gapps-L-4-21-15.zip* onto the Emulator after it has booted. It will prompt you to install the zip and shutdown the device after that.
>       3. After having install the gapps boot up your Emulator again, it will show a dialog about optimizing newly installed packages.
>       4. Go to *Settings > Accounts* and *Add a Google Account.* **Ignore all crashes.**
>       5. After adding the Account, install the *benzo-gapps-M-20151011-signed-chroma-r3.zip* by dragging it onto your Emulator, like in step 2.
>       6. After rebooting after step 5. is done, you should now have working Play Services and Play Store on your Visual Studio Emulator for Android.

Answer (score 0):

One of the biggest problems with the other answers is that people stop looking for an easy solution if they find that awful workaround. Luckily I found the [gapps-lp-20150314](https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=95916177934547569) gapps package that to work just fine with the 10.1'' Marshmallow (6.0.0) Tablet in Visual Studio Emulator for Android.